# Multiple labels in Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Is there a way of specifying multiple labels for an example in the Vowpal Wabbit data format?

I tried comma's and it doesn't complain, but I am not sure if it does what I expect...

So e.g:

```
2,3 | f1:3 f3:23 
2 | f1:2 f3:34
```

The first line is an example that is both in class 2 and in class 3.

I do see some discussion on the [vowpal mailing list](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/vowpal_wabbit/conversations/messages/1419) but I am not sure if anything has happened since.

Tom

Comment: We need more detail. Are you doing some sort of multi-class comparison?

Comment: Hi thanks,

No the task is really straightforward. I have something like 30 classes (they are topics). In the training material (which consists of documents) the examples can belong to more than one class (documents can belong to more than one topic).

So I was just wondering how I should reflect this in a train file in the VW format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should use CSOAA which allows multiple labels.  They need to be natural numbers and less than or equal to K where K is the number of classes.  Like this:

```
1 2 3 class1 | f1:2 f2:3
4 2 5 class2 | f3:7 f5:3
2 3 class3 | f4:2 f2:2
```

For more detail, see the Vowpal Wabbit documentation: https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Cost-Sensitive-One-Against-All-%28csoaa%29-multi-class-example

Comment: That solves my original question.

However, I was actually looking for an multilabel SVM (becuase I want to compare an SVM approach to something else I have).

But, the documentation of CSOAA says that you should leave the cost function alone (so no 'hinge' here, I guess).

Any thoughts as to that..??

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know. It's got a SGDClassifier that actually does exactly what I want. It keeps giving me errors though :-[ (maybe I should start a new topic on that...). That is why I ended up with vw in the first place.